# Ending of Sacred Games

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, sacred-games

Can someone explain the ending of **Sacred Games** (Season 1).

Who is the **character** found tied in a hole?

[image: Person]

Is he dead or alive?

And what is the significance of the items shown present in the place with him  (see images below)?

[image: Mask]
[image: Air supply]
[image: Filtration Module]
[image: Geiger Counter]

Comment: It's a nuclear shelter.

Answer (score 2):

That guy there is Trivedi.

[image: Trivedi, played by Chittaranjan Tripathy]

I bet he is dead, even if Ganesh Gaitonde was claiming that everyone will be dead but Trivedi. Why? Remember when Sartaj (Saif Ali Khan) opens the door, he smells something bad, and that may be his dead body, because he was trapped in there and bound on a chair so he was not able to eat/drink during these days, i.e. after Ganesh Gaitonde’s death and the day Sartaj found this room.

From the first image, that clearly is a radiation mask. So there has to be some radiation attack all over the city. Every other image shows instruments (like [Anti Gas/Radiation Mask](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/MF11B-military-full-face-gas-mask_60684836445.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.32.3b7f2284bI4wVI) [NBC Filteration](https://www.disasterbunkers.com/nbc-filter-systems/), [Geiger counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger_counter)) those are used to fight/survive in radiation attack. He even has dedicated air supply so he only can breath. Right now no one knows why Ganesh Gaitonde wanted to save only Trivedi.

Comment: Gas attack? Geiger counter is for detecting radiations. The chamber is a nuclear shelter.

Comment: Right. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Who is the character found tied in a hole?**

Definitely the tied person is Trivedi, who is the follower of Gaitonde's third father. The following image shows that Sartaj got the proof from that person's pocket which indicates he is **L. K. Trivedi**. 
[image: Trivedi]

**Is he dead or alive?**

Trivedi is dead
(It is shown in Episode-2 ('Matsya'), Season-2)